# Android - I can access ViewModel method from fragment but the method does not return the list

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I recently started studying android kotlin and I am expecting this to have a very simple answer but I have a ViewModel which has a method called getDataComment and I want to call the method from my fragment and provide the needed argument for it. But when I try to call it, there's no build error, it just doesn't show the list.

My method in view model:

```
fun getDataComment(postId: Int) {
        PostRepository().getDataComment(postId).enqueue(object : Callback<List<Comment>>{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Comment>>, response: Response<List<Comment>>) {
                val comments = response.body()
                comments?.let {
                    mPostsComment.value = comments!!
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Comment>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "On Failure: ${t.message}")
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    }
```

Fragment Class

```
class PostDetailFragment : Fragment() {

    var param2: Int = 0
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentPostDetailBinding
    private val viewModel by viewModels<PostCommentViewModel>()

    private val gson: Gson by lazy {
        Gson()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_post_detail, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        checkArguments()
    }

     private fun checkArguments() {
        arguments?.let { bundle ->
            if (bundle.containsKey("POST")) {
                val postString = bundle.getString("POST", "")
                val post: Post = gson.fromJson(postString, Post::class.java)

                binding.postDetailstvTitle.text = post.title
                binding.postDetailstvBody.text = post.body
                param2 = post.id

                viewModel.getDataComment(param2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what it's supposed to look like: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bb66.png)
Here's what I'm getting: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9JJD.png)

Sorry in advance if It's messy this is my first time asking here and let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

Comment: Do you observe `mPostsComment`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm not very familiar with it yet, what does it do?

Comment: well, let's ask you this, what does `mPostsComment.value = comments!!` do ?

Comment: presumably, it is assigning a value to a live data object, right ? do you ever interact with that live data object ? observing on to it is how you get the data out of it

Comment: Ohhhhhh okay that makes sense! Thank you @a_local_nobody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

observe `mPostsComment` inside fragment from viewmodel

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    checkArguments()

    viewModel.mPostsComment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { collectionList ->
                // do whatever you want with collectionList
    })
}
```